# Como pegar esses dados com $.getJson?

Tags: javascript, getjson

Já tentei vários códigos aqui da comunidade mas não consigo abstrair esse dados dessa API em Json.

http://governotransparente.com.br/transparencia/api/v1/json/4507590/pessoas/Jose

Já existe várias publicações semelhantes, mas não me resolveram o problema mesmo que sigo todo os tutoriais.

Comment: Não é! Esse problema é específico.

Comment: Está dando algum erro?

Comment: você não está conseguindo, pois da erro de `CORS`

Comment: `Failed to load http://governotransparente.com.br/transparencia/api/v1/json/4507590/pessoas/Jose: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Não consigo pegar os dados disponíveis em Json.